# How to fix Geoserver Wingdings font issue on ubuntu 17.10 server?

Tags: geoserver, truetype, sld

I have SLD stylesheet that uses Wingdings font as shown here:

```
<sld:WellKnownName>ttf://Wingdings#0xE0</sld:WellKnownName>
                                        <sld:Fill>
                                            <sld:CssParameter name="fill">#0000FF</sld:CssParameter>
                                            <sld:CssParameter name="fill-opacity">0.5</sld:CssParameter>                                    
                                        </sld:Fill>
```

But below error is thrown by Geoserver:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The specified mark ttf://Wingdings#0xE0 was not found!
    at org.geotools.renderer.style.SLDStyleFactory.createMarkStyle(SLDStyleFactory.java:721)
    at org.geotools.renderer.style.SLDStyleFactory.createPointStyle(SLDStyleFactory.java:684)
    at org.geotools.renderer.style.SLDStyleFactory.getGraphicStroke(SLDStyleFactory.java:1017)
    at org.geotools.renderer.style.SLDStyleFactory.createLineStyle(SLDStyleFactory.java:516)
    at org.geotools.renderer.style.SLDStyleFactory.createStyleInternal(SLDStyleFactory.java:383)
    at org.geotools.renderer.style.SLDStyleFactory.createStyle(SLDStyleFactory.java:333)
    at org.geotools.renderer.style.SLDStyleFactory.createStyle(SLDStyleFactory.java:296)
    at org.geotools.renderer.lite.StreamingRenderer.processSymbolizers(StreamingRenderer.java:2608)
    at org.geotools.renderer.lite.StreamingRenderer.processFeature(StreamingRenderer.java:2490)
    at org.geotools.renderer.lite.StreamingRenderer.drawPlain(StreamingRenderer.java:2325)
```

I tried to copy Wingding.ttf to geoserver_data /styles folder where my SLD style also lives but it does not work and throws exception that it does not support the font. My application has stopped working on ubuntu server but works on mac osx system. How to solve this issue?

Geoserver version is 2.13

Comment: duplicate of https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/286366/how-to-draw-right-arrow-symbol-in-sld-for-geoserver

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a duplicate of https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/286366/how-to-draw-right-arrow-symbol-in-sld-for-geoserver which is the correct site for this question and it has been answered there.